# how to get multiple field's value from multiple key at a time in redis?

Tags: redis, nosql

i am new in redis . I want to know how to get multiple field's value from multiple sets in redis. is it possible in Redis . and if possible then how. 
Example

```
HSET myhash1 field1 "Hello"
HSET myhash2 field2 "Hello"
HSET myhash3 field3 "Hello"
    I want to get all the three field's value from different sets at a time?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Lua Scripting](http://redis.io/commands/eval) for this.

Example:

```lua
local a={}
a[1] = redis.call('hget',KEYS[1], KEYS[2])
a[2] = redis.call('hget',KEYS[3], KEYS[4])
a[3] = redis.call('hget',KEYS[5], KEYS[6])
return a
```

Coded for simplicity, ofcourse you'd make the parameters more flexible. You can also use cjson for input as well as output (if you keep in mind that serialisation eats up a tiny bit of CPU).

Another way is using [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining), but I guess your question is about doing this atomically.

Hope this helps, TW